# Google protobuf adds weird 0xff values when decoding bytes which are larger or equal to 0x80 from message

Tags: encoding, hex, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I have this message file:

```
message samplemessage
{
    optional bytes byte_string = 1;
}
```

And this program which uses this protobuf file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "mymessages.pb.h"
using namespace std;




// Main function:   Reads the entire packet from file,
//   modifies the string_data field and then writes the modified version back to disk.


void print_hex2(const char* string, int length) {
for (int i = 0; i<length;i++) {
    printf("%02x", (unsigned int) *string++);
}
printf("\n");
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
// Verify that the version of the library that we linked against is
// compatible with the version of the headers we compiled against.
GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION;

if (argc != 3) {
    cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " PACKET_FILE OUTPUT_FILE" << endl;
    return -1;
}
samplemessage thing;

{
    // Read the existing address book.
    fstream input(argv[1], ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (!input) {
        cout << argv[1] << ": File not found.   Creating a new file." << endl;
    } else if (!thing.ParseFromIstream(&input)) {
        cerr << "Failed to parse packet file." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}




print_hex2(thing.byte_string().c_str(), strlen(thing.byte_string().c_str()));

printf("%s\n", thing.byte_string().c_str());

unsigned char stuff[10000] = "\x41\x80";


thing.set_byte_string(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(stuff));


printf("%s\n", thing.byte_string().c_str());


print_hex2(thing.byte_string().c_str(), strlen(thing.byte_string().c_str()));

{
    // Write the new packet to disk.
    fstream output(argv[2], ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);
    if (!thing.SerializeToOstream(&output)) {
        cerr << "Failed to write packet file." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}

// Optional:    Delete all global objects allocated by libprotobuf.
google::protobuf::ShutdownProtobufLibrary();

return 0;
}
```

This program when compiled generates this output for me:

```
41ffffff80
```

But when i change the `\x80` to `\x7f` the ff values do not appear and I get this output:

```
417f
```

Looking at the output file with xxd I do not see these ff bytes anywhere:

```
00000000: 0a02 4180                                ..A.
```

Why is this? Is this some encoding thing? I thought that the bytes in protobuf encode raw bytes but that is obviously not the case here? Why are the ff bytes being added?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> printf("%02x", (unsigned int) *string++);

Apparently `char` is signed on your platform, which is quite common.

Then when you cast `(unsigned int)((char)0x80))`, the `0x80` is evaluated as `-128` and expanded to `int` first. This results as `0xffffff80`

Try this instead:

> printf("%02x", (unsigned int)(unsigned char) *string++);